# Can ActiveMQ cluster have brokers running on different transport protocol?

Tags: java, apache, activemq-classic, message-queue, failover

I want to know if it is possible to have a failover cluster of Active MQ in which brokers are running on different transport protocol.
Say, one is running on ssl://, other is on tcp://. 
Example:
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,ssl://localhost:61626).

If yes, then what would be the factory class to use?
ActiveMQConnectionFactory or ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix both SSL and Non-SSL based transport connections in a failover URI (with a bit of caution since the TCP one isn't secure).  You would generally use the ActiveMQConnectionFactory in either case as you only need to use the ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory if you need to control the key and trust store configuration in code for some reason.  The SSL configuration can be done on the URI so it is possible to mix them for failover if you really wanted to.

Refer to the docs of the ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory for why you only need it under certain circumstances:

> An ActiveMQConnectionFactory that allows access to the key and trust managers
>      used for SslConnections. There is no reason to use this class unless SSL is
>      being used AND the key and trust managers need to be specified from within
>      code. In fact, if the URI passed to this class does not have an "ssl" scheme,
>      this class will pass all work on to its superclass.